Issue with Fetching Data from GitHub.io via TCP
I'm encountering an issue while trying to fetch data using a Cavli Inc. LTE CAT1.bis Module (Model: C16QS) from a GitHub.io hosted server. Below is the sequence of AT commands I'm using and the response I receive:
// AT+CDNSGIP="airy-039.github.io"
// AT+CIPSTART=TCP,airy-039.github.io,443,1
// AT+CIPSEND=78
// GET /filey/Seria1_Test_Terminal.ino.bin HTTP/1.1\r\n
// Host: airy-039.github.io\r\n
// Connection: close\r\n
// \r\n
// AT+CIPCLOSE

enter image description here
Problem:
The module successfully establishes a connection to the server (airy-039.github.io) but encounters a 400 Bad Request error when trying to send a request.
Additional Information:
The server is hosted on GitHub.io.
The LTE module firmware version is V1.4.5.
The hardware version is C16QS_HW_V2.21(2711).
I have verified that the server and URL are accessible through other means (e.g., web browser).
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
